# Program design with polymorphism and differing data structures

Tags: c++, boost, vector, polymorphism, pointers

I think I have a design issue here and I would really appreciate your help.

I have a class Base representing a basic algorithm.

```
class BaseAlgo: public Algo<double>
{
public:

/// data structures
// ...
// 
 struct Item {
    double profit;
    double weight;
    double xjSolution;
 };

 typedef std::pair<double, std::vector<Item>::iterator> ScaledItem;

protected:

 std::vector<Item> & items_;
 boost::ptr_vector<ScaledItem> largeItems_;
}
```

The BaseAlgo has some functions, some of them virtual, others not.

As a derived class I have

```
class DerivedAlgo: public BaseAlgo
{
public:

/// enhanced data structures
// ...
// 

 struct DerivedScaledItem : ScaledItem {
    int additional;
 };
 }
```

In my virtual functions which I overload in DerivedAlgo, I need access to the additional parameter of DerivedScaledItem which is not quite the original intent of polymorphism. Is it somehow possible or do you propose a different design approach? I am open to anything at the moment as I am completely stuck.

Right now, the largeItems_ member ptr_vector in BaseAlgo holds ScaledItems (internally as pointers). I thought, I could use this somehow like this:

```
// in DerivedAlgo

void someMethod(std::vector<Item>::iterator someiterator){
   DerivedScaledItem doubledItem = {};

   doubledItem.first = 4.5;
   doubledItem.second = someiterator;
   doubledItem.additional= 2;
   largeItems_.push_back(new UnboundedScaledItem(doubledItem));
   boost::ptr_vector<DerivedScaledItem>::iterator it = largeItems_.begin();
   std::cout << "added large item " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

When I cout the just added object, additional is set to 2. But after that, calling the getter for largeItems_, the additional field will be set back to 0, only the two fields which are known in ScaledItem are then set.

```
// in BaseAlgo
const boost::ptr_vector<ScaledItem>& getLargeItems() const
{
    return largeItems_;
}

// from my test.cpp
DerivedAlgo obj;
// ... define someiterator
obj.someMethod(someiterator);
boost::ptr_vector<BaseAlgo::ScaledItem> largeItems = knapsack.getLargeItems();
boost::ptr_vector<DerivedAlgo::DerivedScaledItem>::iterator it = largeItems.begin();
std::cout << "read large item " << *it << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't tell boost how to clone your ptr_vector-s elements, like described here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#cloneability

So in this line, where you create a copy of the vector (you could avoid this by declaring `largeItems` as a reference), they get copied via the constructor of `ScaledItem`, which looses your additional member.

```
boost::ptr_vector<BaseAlgo::ScaledItem> largeItems = knapsack.getLargeItems();
```

Regarding your question about another design:

- You could pass the type of the vectors elements as a template parameter to the base class.
- You could move the vector into the derived class, and provide only (virtual, abstract) functions to access single elements in the base class. If the base class shall also be able to create elements, you may need some kind of factory method. Because you don't want the base kind of elements in the vector.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your answer! I like the idea of the template parameter, I will try this out this evening.
Also, I will try whether declaring largeItems in my test code as a reference will solve the issue but it seems to make sense!

Comment: Ok, declaring largeItems as a const reference solved the issue. But I have a follow up question:
What happens when I have iterators of BaseAlgo::ScaledItems as function arguments of virtual functions? Is the additional parameter automativally lost when I declare an iterator of the base type?

Comment: :) Already solved, I used dynamic cast and changed ScaledItem from a typedef to a real struct with virtual destructor to make it work.